# Is there any speed advantage of using setkey with str_extract in string column?

Tags: r, data.table

I'm starting now to learn how to use data.table package and one of the tasks I'm doing is extract specific words from a text column where in each row I have one product name. Example of one row:

```
The product XXXX is used in food tests.
```

In this case I need to look if one of the words on my products list is this `XXXX` and extract the name of the product from the column.

```
DT[, `:=` (PRODUCT_NAME = str_extract(PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION, PRODUCT_LIST))
```

Is there any speed gain in using this column as a key in this search and extraction process?

Comment: You might want to generate a large dataset and time the different variation and observe the timing results

Comment: My instinct says "no". I don't think a regex / string search engine would benefit particularly from the input being alphabetical, unless maybe your target substring is always at the beginning of the word